# Socket occupied by TIME_WAIT status

Tags: linux, time-wait

I can see TIME_WAIT on port 9180 with "netstat -an cmd" and see nothing with "lsof -i:9180".

My application could not start and report the socket had been occupied.

Comment: The *port* is in TIME_WAIT state. Not the socket. The socket is already closed, and so is the peer's.

Answer (score 1):

A very good explanation of this problem is given in these links, [link1](https://serverfault.com/questions/478691/avoid-time-wait-connections), [link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/450055/lot-of-fin-wait2-close-wait-last-ack-and-time-wait-in-haproxy).

To solve this problem, wait for some time so that timeout of fin-wait could happen and port finally moved to closed state.